# How to install previous Node version in 32 bit Win 7?

Tags: node.js

I have a 32 bit Win7 machine, and I need to install specific version of Node(V 13, https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.0.0/)

However I can not find executable files for Win 32 bit system, All are for 64/86 system.

Is there any way ? Or am I at dead end.

Any Node version that compatible with Win 7 32 bit is fine for me.

Comment: x86 builds are usually the 32-bit builds (vs x64). Did you try one?